# Mysql Query Error 1054 - Unknown column in the 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I'm learning MYSQL FULL JOIN queries using the Northwind database. This is my query,

```
SELECT customers.CompanyName, orders.OrderID
FROM customers
FULL JOIN orders ON customers.CustomerID=orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY customers.CompanyName;
```

Customers table schema,

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `CustomerID` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `CompanyName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ContactName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ContactTitle` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fax` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Image` longblob,
  `ImageThumbnail` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`),
  KEY `City` (`City`),
  KEY `CompanyName` (`CompanyName`),
  KEY `PostalCode` (`PostalCode`),
  KEY `Region` (`Region`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Orders table schema,

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `OrderID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerID` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmployeeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OrderDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `RequiredDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShippedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipVia` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Freight` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `ShipName` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipAddress` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipCity` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipRegion` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipPostalCode` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShipCountry` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`OrderID`),
  KEY `CustomerID` (`CustomerID`),
  KEY `EmployeeID` (`EmployeeID`),
  KEY `OrderDate` (`OrderDate`),
  KEY `ShippedDate` (`ShippedDate`),
  KEY `ShipPostalCode` (`ShipPostalCode`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11078 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this is MySQL server version `5.7.35 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

I am getting `#1054 - Unknown column 'customers.CompanyName' in 'field list'`

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: MySQL does not support FULL JOIN. You probably want LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql don`t support full join,but oracle support
you can use 
select customers.CompanyName, orders.OrderID from customers,orders where customers.CustomerID=orders.CustomerID order by
customers.CompanyName;